# SQL query to select dates between two dates where dates are stored with commas

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, jquery-multidatespicker

I'm using [Multidatespicker](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/) so I have dates in my database as follow:

```
ID    POST  KEY                  VALUE
1     1     multipledates        20151020, 20151015, 20151101
2     2     multipledates        20151103
3     3     multipledates        20151022, 20151010, 20151202, 20160410
...
```

Then I have 'date_start' and 'date_end'. I need to select dates between this dates.

This SQL query only works in my example with ID2 (because it hasn't commas)

```
SELECT ... BETWEEN $date_start AND $date_end
```

The solution would be to use something like 'LIKE' but not if possible:

```
SELECT ... BETWEEN LIKE '%$date_start%' AND LIKE '%$date_end%'
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: (The obvious thing it to change the table so that it has only value per row)

Comment: The logical solution would be use single values for data but I wonder if it would be possible

Comment: More accurately, the correct thing to do would be to normalize your data.

Comment: redesign your data structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should redesign your schema for sure.

But just as a study case you can:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22755/4

```
SELECT t.id,
   t.date
FROM (SELECT
  t1.id,
  DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.value, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1)) `date`
FROM
  numbers 
  INNER JOIN t1
  ON CHAR_LENGTH(t1.value)
     -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(t1.value, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1
ORDER BY
  id, n ) t
WHERE t.date BETWEEN $date_start AND $date_end
```

Notice this solution expects that you have `numbers` table with record values from 1 to max number of elements in your `value`list column.

(c) code based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/17942691/4421474